# Word 2010 "object error" during template load

Tags: vbscript, word-2010

We have recently upgraded to Office 2010 from 2003.  VBScript type code that was working fine in 2003 now fails intermittently in 2010, with 'object error' or 'command failed'.

From what I've managed to work out, this appears to be the result of the Normal template still downloading/loading, despite the CreateObject call completing.  When the code works, it seems that normal has loaded quickly.

Code:

```
Dim oWord As Object
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True
Set document = oWord.Documents.Open("\\networkshare\networkshare\mytemplate.dot")
```

The code fails on "Set document ="

I have looked for solutions to this however I haven't found any trace of people having this issue elsewhere.   If I insert a delay between oWord.Visible and Set document, the issue is resolved.   I'd prefer to fix this properly though, as we often deal with many hundreds of documents in one run.
I have tried to detect the completion of loading for Normal, however have been unsuccessful in this regard.

Has anyone else seen this issue and found a solution?

Many thanks

Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should try "grab" a Word object before creating it.

```
Dim oWord As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set oWord = GetObject(,"Word.Application")
If oWord Is Nothing Then Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

Alternatively, disable alerts, and put the `oWord.Documents.Open` into a loop. For a few times with a second wait in between or until the .dot template is opened, then re-enable alerts.

Since it's on a network share, latency most likely be higher than on local storage devices. That may explain why if a wait works fine.

Depending on what the .dot template do, you might want it Visible after it is opened.

Comment: Hi Patrick,  

I tried using GetObject, but The issue still remains for the first document created.
This would be fine if I could guarantee a Word instance would already be open.  
  
I ended up going with your second suggestion, which I'm not convinced is the best in terms of best practice, however the only option that works:  
  
    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")  
  
On Error Resume Next  
 
Set oDoc = Nothing  
Do While oDoc Is Nothing  
 Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open([template path])  
 <Wait 50ms>  
Loop  
  
On Error Goto 0  
  
Thanks for your help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Code that was used to solve this issue:

```
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
On Error Resume Next
Set oDoc = Nothing
Do While oDoc Is Nothing
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open([template path])
<Wait 50ms>
Loop On Error Goto 0
```

Off topic, but would be useful for others with this issue:
As of Word 2010, the ActivePrinter property is now case sensitive, so you have to ensure capitalisation is the same as shown in the printers dialog.
The error Word 2010 generates when setting this property fails is "Microsoft Word: There is a printer error"

Comment: Nice pick up on the Default Printer Settings. I have seen Macros on some Templates which **ASSUMED** the printer port is the same for all computers (which is proven wrong for me) and caused errors. In your case the template macro should do more than assume printer available on a particular port.